# connecting android app to rails server

Tags: android, ruby-on-rails, web-deployment

i am new into developing in general, so i am made a social network web application using ruby on rails but only in a localhost , and i made sign-up/sign-in form in an android app.

what i want is basically to have an online server that will have my website code and database and domain , and how to send the user data when signing up/in in the android app and sent some back too

Obviously, I am not looking for a code or a simple answer, i just want links or any useful resources to start with.

thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you want an application server or a web server :) ?

Comment: @user3784668 can u till the difference ? :D

Comment: http://www.javaworld.com/article/2077354/learn-java/app-server-web-server-what-s-the-difference.html 

and..

http://www.diffen.com/difference/Application_Server_vs_Web_Server

Answer (score 2):

i'm not a RoR people, but if you want to communicate android to web, you need create a web api on RoR which handle signup, signin event and return json format. Then in your android app, you can use HTTP REQUEST to get or post data
http://www.androidhive.info/2011/10/android-making-http-requests/